# I get {"error":"unauthorized"} when trying to run .php file on Apache server

Tags: php, apache, localhost, mamp

php file that I need to run on my localhost server. I have downloaded MAMP and changed the Apache port to 80. I also added my file to the htdocs folder and when I run the server and go to localhost I can see my .php file in the list. But when I click on it I get the following error: {"error":"unauthorized"} and nothing else. Im using the file for my ios app and i need to know that I can access the file via my localhost adress. Im very new to php so If anyone could help I would be very grateful. Thanks.

The Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json');

$appID = $_POST['appID'];
$restAPI = $_POST['restAPI'];
$alert = $_POST['alert'];
$channels = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['channels']);
$channels = explode(",",$channels);

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';

$data = json_encode(
    array(
        'channels' => $channels, 
        'type' => 'ios',
        'data' => array(
                    'alert' => $alert,
                    'sound' => 'push.caf',
                    'badge' => 'Increment'
                    )
            ),true
);

$curl = curl_init();

$curlArray = array(
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, 
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $appID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $restAPI,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlArray);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: You'll need to describe what the PHP file does if you want help with it.

Comment: Show some code... Besides, the error that shows up looks to me like a JSON string, chances are the php script is returning a JSON-encoded error message

Comment: Ok im not the one who wrote the code but I will post some. The code come's from a GitHub source.